# Save Layout as Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-linearlayout

I want to save my Linearlayout as an bmp.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_QrCode" >

        <Space
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="185dp"
                android:layout_height="185dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView_qrcode" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="417dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/space2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:id="@+id/textView_QrSticker_label"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/space2"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:id="@+id/textView_QrSticker_serial"
                android:layout_below="@+id/space2"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Therefore I use the following code to perform this:

```
        public Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view) {
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            view.draw(canvas);
            return bitmap;
        }
```

But If I run this code my bitmap only contains the `ImageView` (ImageView_qrcode). I checked it. If I inflate the Linearview the `TextViews` are shown correctly but the output bmp only contains the `ImageView` does somebody know why?

Comment: So the problem is you're not seeing the textviews? When are you setting the text on the textviews? If you're doing it the same moment you're trying to draw the main linearlayout, you may need to to call the viewToBitmap method on a post.

Comment: The problem is  that I can see the textviews in the Linearlayout but not in the "drawed" bitmap.
These are the steps I perform:
1. set the Image to the ImageView
2. set the label textview
3. set the serial textview
4. call the getBitmapFromView method

all in 1 method

Comment: try calling getBitmapFromView via post (i.e., myView.post(new Runnable() { ... viewToBitmap(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Gil Moshayof it works now!

After calling the getBitmapFromView method via post it works fine

```
                qrCodeSticker.setImageBitmap(((MainActivity) getActivity()).createQrCode(stringForQrCode));
                labelSticker.setText(qrDataList[1]);
                serialSticker.setText(qrDataList[2]);


                qrcodefinal.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        qrcodefinal.setImageBitmap(MainActivity.getBitmapFromView(qrStickerLayout));
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 6):

You can to try this solution:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null) {
    bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    } else {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

There is solution with drawing cache:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view){
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    return view.getDrawingCache();
}
```

Comment: With this code I see that the whole heigth and width gets saved. But the Image still not contains the TextViews....

Answer (score 2):

Use setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

```
View content = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_QrCode);
    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
    File file = new File("/sdcard/" + yourimagename + ".png");
    try {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
        ostream.close();
        content.invalidate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
            content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    }
```